# How to update my WP8 Silverlight app tile every one minute?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, live-tile, background-task

In my app, I've created the mechanism to create a custom tile. Lets say, `CreateTile()` this is the function which will create live tile and also will update the value.

But I want to update the live tile automatically every one minute. I have heard of Background Task Agent and Scheduled Notifications. But I don't know how to use them.

Can anyone help me out, assuming that there is already a function `CreateTile()` which updates my tile information?

Answer (score 0):

Periodic background agents run at roughly 30 minutes interval. You cannot configure this interval.
Here are the details for background agents: [Background agents for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I implement periodic background agent in my app?

Comment: This article gives a step by step guide to add background agents
[How to implement background agents for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I know but I can't. That's why I am seeking for some guidance here

Comment: The second MSDN article is quite to-the-point for a tutorial. Have you checked it? It's different from the first link I gave.